# How to SUM specific cells in a range depending on the posistion and value of different cells in another range?

Tags: excel, vba, sum

The goal for this function in to sum specific cells in a range depending on the value and position of other cells in a different range.

Here is an image so it is more clear:

[image]

The answer for Column M would be = 2+4+6+9 =   21
The answer for Column P would be = 3+7+10 = 20

There are 20 different "Precio, Precio2, Precio3,..." that are under "Licitante 1, Licitante 2, ..." which is why I used CASES.

Recap, if a cell in column "M" is >0 then the function should select the cell on column "H" which is on the same row, do this for all the cells in said range and add them.

I have this so far:

```
Function ImporteLic(lic As String)

Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer

Select Case lic

    Case "Licitante 1"
        For Each cell In Range("M13:M50")
            If ActiveCell.Value > 0 Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5) = i
            End If
        Next cell

    ImporteLic = worksheetfuntion.Sum(i)


End Select
End Function
```

I guess i am missing something in the part where all the cells that meet the criteria add up.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried Application.SUMIFS()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a ton of issues with the code you posted. Try this and see if works.

```
Function ImporteLic(lic As String) As Double

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change name

        Dim col As Long
        col = .Rows(1).Find(lic, lookat:=xlWhole).Column

        Dim checkRange As Range
        Set checkRange = .Range(.Cells(3, col), .Cells(50, col))

        Dim sumRange As Range
        Set sumRange = .Range("H3:H50")

        Dim addEmUp As Double
        addEmUp = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(checkRange, ">0", sumRange)

    End With

  ImporteLic = addEmUp

End Function
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much, and if you have time, would you mind giving me some pointers as to why my code had issues? Im new at this so trying to learn, thanks again!